# Clases: Declaración de atributos en el inicializador y en los métodos

Tags: python, poo

Me estoy iniciando en POO. Como ejercicio, he creado el siguiente script.

```
class ConstructorFrecuencias:
    def __init__(self, lista_valores):
        self.lista_valores = lista_valores       
    
    def calcula_frecuencias(self, lista_valores):  
        # Serie con valores únicos  
        frecuencias = pd.value_counts(self.lista_valores )
        # DataFrame con la columna Fi
        frecuencias = pd.DataFrame(frecuencias, columns = ["Fi"])
        frecuencias.index.names = ['Xi']
        frecuencias.reset_index(inplace=True)

        # Frecuencia absoluta acumulada utilizando numpy
        array = np.array(frecuencias["Fi"] )
        frecuencias["FrecAbsAcum (F)"] = np.cumsum(array , dtype=float)

        # Frecuencia relativa
        frecuencias["FrecRel (fr)"] = 0
        for i in range (0, frecuencias.shape[0]):
            frecuencias.iloc[i, 3] = frecuencias.iloc[i, 1]/frecuencias["Fi"].sum()

        print ("Número de observaciones :", frecuencias["Fi"].sum())
        print ("\nSuma de fecuencias relativas :", frecuencias["FrecRel (fr)"].sum())
        return frecuencias
        
tabla =  ConstructorFrecuencias(lista_ventas)      
        
tabla. calcula_frecuencias(lista_ventas)
```

He tardado en hacerlo funcionar bien porque, en las sentenias de creación del objeto y de llamada al método a través de la clase. entendía que solamente tenía que incluir una lista con valores, en una de ellas. Como he acertado a base de realizar pruebas y no acabo de entenderlo muy bien, agradecería aclaración a las siguientes preguntas:

- En el constructor estoy declarando como atributo de la clase, la lista "lista_valores". Este atributo servirá también para todos los métodos de ésta clase.
- Al crear el objeto "tabla =  ConstructorFrecuencias(lista_ventas)  " , entiende que, para este objeto,  lista_valores va a ser lista_ventas.
- El método "calcula_frecuencias(self, lista_valores)" , ¿por qué tenemos que volver a incluir el parámetro "lista_valores" y no entiende que tiene que usar el atributo lista_valores de la clase?, que al crear el objeto hemos asociado a "lista_ventas?.
- Si para llamar al método a traves del objeto, tengo que volver a incluir una lista haciendo "tabla.calcula_frecuencias(lista_ventas)" , para qué me sirve haber declarado en el constructor que "lista_ventas" servía para toda la clase?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vamos paso a paso pues

```
class ConstructorFrecuencias:
    def __init__(self, lista_valores):
        self.lista_valores = lista_valores       
    
    def calcula_frecuencias(self):  # Primero, quitar el parámetro de aquí, no hace falta
        # Serie con valores únicos  
        frecuencias = pd.value_counts(self.lista_valores) # Si lo usas así, no necesitas tenerlo declarado en el método
        # DataFrame con la columna Fi
        frecuencias = pd.DataFrame(frecuencias, columns = ["Fi"])
        frecuencias.index.names = ['Xi']
        frecuencias.reset_index(inplace=True)

        # Frecuencia absoluta acumulada utilizando numpy
        array = np.array(frecuencias["Fi"] )
        frecuencias["FrecAbsAcum (F)"] = np.cumsum(array , dtype=float)

        # Frecuencia relativa
        frecuencias["FrecRel (fr)"] = 0
        for i in range (0, frecuencias.shape[0]):
            frecuencias.iloc[i, 3] = frecuencias.iloc[i, 1]/frecuencias["Fi"].sum()

        print ("Número de observaciones :", frecuencias["Fi"].sum())
        print ("\nSuma de fecuencias relativas :", frecuencias["FrecRel (fr)"].sum())
        return frecuencias
        
tabla =  ConstructorFrecuencias(lista_ventas)      
        
tabla.calcula_frecuencias() # No necesitas pasarlo ya que no tiene parámetros ahora
```

Los dos primeros puntos están correctos, el único problema que tienes está en la definición del método, que luego te obliga a incluir el parámetro!

- *El método "calcula_frecuencias(self, lista_valores)" , ¿por qué tenemos que volver a incluir el parámetro "lista_valores" y no entiende que tiene que usar el atributo lista_valores de la clase?, que al crear el objeto hemos asociado a "lista_ventas?.*

**Respuesta**: No tienes por qué, tal como tenías definido el método esperaba un parámetro, pero en realidad luego usabas el atributo de clase a través del self.lista_valores, con lo cual nunca estabas usando el parámetro que le pasabas

- *Si para llamar al método a traves del objeto, tengo que volver a incluir una lista haciendo "tabla.calcula_frecuencias(lista_ventas)" , para qué me sirve haber declarado en el constructor que "lista_ventas" servía para toda la clase?.*

**Respuesta**: No hace falta, de hecho ni siquiera lo estabas usando!

Comment: Efectivamente, estoy pidiendo la variable 'lista_valores' en la definición de la función pero luego no la uso en ningún lugar del código de la función, ya que  'lista_valores' dentro de "def calcula_frecuencias(self, lista_valores)" no es lo mismo que self.lista_valores. El primero pertenece solo a la función. El segundo pertenece a la clase y es compartido por todos los métodos de la clase.